# Can't find log window in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: logging, intellij-idea

Can't find log window in the left bottom side of Intellij IDEA.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a known issue:

- [IDEA-171990](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171990) Run/Debug configuration - Logs broken

Should be fixed in the next update (2017.1.4+ and 2017.2+).

The issue occurs if the log file doesn't exist or is removed during the server startup.

Comment: My version is 2016.2. But reinstalling of IDEA didnt help me (settings werent imported)

Comment: omg. Solved by adding new Log File Entry in the Configuration Window.